# How can a table be a field type in jHipster jdl?

Tags: jhipster, jdl

Tables

[image: 1]

I'm having a problem generating these tables using JHipster jdl with mysql. I need to know if I can create a field with a table as type or if a field can have a JSON type and how. If there's any other solution feel free to contribute, Thanks in advance.

```
entity Note {
   Min Float
   Max Float
}

entity Product {
   price Note
   price2020 Note
   price2021 Note
   price2022 Note
}
```

Comment: min and max should be lower case. Here is info on how to make the relationship you're looking for. 
https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design should be expressed as relations

```
entity Note {
   Min Float
   Max Float
}

entity Product {

}

relationship OneToOne {
    Product{price} to Note
    Product{price2020} to Note
    Product{price2021} to Note
    Product{price2022} to Note
}
```

However, I seriously question your design to have one column/relation per year, it's more a spreadsheet habit and it just does not scale. Each year you will have to modify your database and code.

I would rather consider adding a relation table that maps a product/year to a price.